# Why compilation error in this code snippet?

Tags: java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        short x = 10;
        x = x * 5;
        System.out.print(x);
    }
}
```

I am expecting the output as 50. Why is it showing a compilation error? In C programming the expression x = x * 5 will be converted to integer internally, right? So I was expecting the same in Java.

Comment: Java is **not** C. Do not expect it to behave like C. The problem is `x * 5` is an integer (32 bits in Java) and you are trying to assign it to a `short`. To further aggravate you, I will point out `x *= 5;` is perfectly legal.

Comment: *Main.java:4: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to short* Tells you what the error is. And actually, you half know yourself: *the expression x = x * 5 will be converted to integer internally, right?*

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
byte b = 120;
short s = 10;
```

The above are permitted as the compiler recognizes that the assigned values are within the range of positive values for the target type (7 bits for byte and 15 bits for short).

However, when doing something like  `s = s + 10;`
the right hand side is evaluated as an `int` and thus cannot be reassigned by into a short without a cast.  `s = (short)(s + 10)`.

But `s += 10;` is permitted since it is an assignment operation and thus no casting is required.

Check out [Numeric Contexts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6) in the Java Language Specification for this and other related information.